# Send data from Flex to servlet

Tags: apache-flex, servlet-3.0

I want to send value(_sectionName in examples) from flex end to servlet but I can't send data from flex end to servlet. What is the solution?

```
                  var url:String="http://localhost:8080/xyz/UploadServlet";
          var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
          request.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
          var variables:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
          variables.sectionName=_sectionName;
          variables.reviewType=_sectionName;
          request.data= variables;          
         _fileRef.upload(request);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you provided (assuming the URL is ok and that it _is_ a file upload you want to do). So what exactly is going wrong? Error messages?

Comment: is there any `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` method in your servlet. If not please define one as you are sending your URLVariables in POST method.